# where to store users' information(personal details, username and password) in visual basic?

Tags: database, vb.net, vb6, authentication, passwords

I'm  a newbie in visual basic. I'm doing a login system. 
I'm  done with the GUI. 
but for the programming part, I want to know where to store new user's information along with the username and password.
I've done research. seems like it has something to do with database.

p/s: I'm looking for high security in storing data to prevent hacking.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you need or want user/pw in a VB6 application. You can retrieve the user from the OS easily, and its already been authenticated. Thus you seldom need any "login system" at all. If your program is talking to something else that wants authentication (database credentials?) just pass the info there securely. If you just want to limit who can run your program set access rights on the EXE.  Create a Group, secure execution to this Group, add allowed users to the Group.  Easy.

Answer (score 0):

Like you've found out yourself, the login information is usually stored in a database. To make it more secure, use encryption algorithm for storing this kind of information. You could use MD5, but it's quite easily reversed. I would recommend using BCrypt.